# Start with UNICODE supported WINAPI programming

Tags: c, windows, winapi, unicode, unicode-string

I started developing an application in C using WINAPIs. I want my application to be UNICODE supported.

> I am using mingw with gcc compiler. What should I do to make my app
>   UNICODE support.  It should work in all versions of windows starting
>   from xp.  And I wish my application to work in all languanges.

Can you please provide me some guidelines on this and Do's and Dont's.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Your question is unfortunately far too vague to effectively answer.

2) Furthermore, "supporting Unicode" is *not* the same as "supporting different languages".

3) Finally, even Unicode (a small part of the broader topic of "internationalization") has differences depending on your Windows version, Windows compiler, and target audience.

STRONG SUGGESTION:

1) Start here for an overview of "Unicode":

- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

2) Here are a couple of good overviews for "internationalization":

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318661%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

3) Here are a couple of links for programming an application in multiple different languages:

- http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/gnu_libc_guide/Translation-with-gettext.html
- [Implementing Globalization / Multilingual feature in win32 API application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653874/implementing-globalization-multilingual-feature-in-win32-api-application)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I will fix the problems in my question. can you expalin me your second point bit more please possibly with some links..